Is Analysis Services DMV query executing "on server" or "on database"
I am doing some DMV queries on SQL Server Analysis Service, like SELECT * FROM $system.DISCOVER_SESSIONS. This query will return data for all databases on the server, so it's not really database-specific. When I connect to the server through AdomdConnection, I don't specify the database/catalog in the connection string, and the query still works. However I noticed that a database is always associated with this connection, and it's usually the first database on the list of available ones on the server.
My question is

do these kind of queries actually burden the database in question, i.e., if for whatever reason we would have many DMV queries that check the server sessions, do they all query the automatically-chosen first database on the list, and therefore impact (performance-wise) any users who might actually do "real" queries on this database?
Or is this kind of DMV query just impacting the server itself, not in any way the database and therefore the performance impact is the same no matter which database is chosen?

Possibly a shorter way of phrasing it would be: are performance impacts of a DMV query server-related or database-related?


When I connect to the server through AdomdConnection, I don't specify the database/catalog in the connection string, and the query still works.

When you don't specify a database in the connection string, the database engine will set your database context to the default that is mapped to the Login that authenticated with the server. If no default is set for that Login, then I believe the engine defaults to the master database. Most DMVs are accessible from any database.

do these kind of queries actually burden the database in question, i.e., if for whatever reason we would have many DMV queries that check the server sessions, do they all query the automatically-chosen first database on the list, and therefore impact (performance-wise) any users who might actually do "real" queries on this database?

For the most part, that's not really a thing. Except for specific kinds of queries, such as ones that alter the database specifically and / or cause it to go offline, running a query from a specific database context doesn't cause any kind of materialized burden against that specific database.

Or is this kind of DMV query just impacting the server itself, not in any way the database and therefore the performance impact is the same no matter which database is chosen?

The server is composed of hardware resources. So any kind of query or process will surely consume some amount of those resources in order to execute. Even if the query targets only specific objects of a specific database, the hardware resources are still server-level provisioned. (Putting aside the conversation of  limiting a database's access to those resources with Resource Governor.) Of course less server resources being available affects all databases on that server.
So yes, pretty much it doesn't matter which database you execute most of the DMVs from, from a performance perspective. The impact will be consistent regardless.

Possibly a shorter way of phrasing it would be: are performance impacts of a DMV query server-related or database-related?

Server related.
